# Integrating Azure Services with Route53 Hosted Domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-active-directory, amazon-route53

I have a domain hosted on AWS Route53, but would like to enable Azure services such as Azure AD and 365 to be addressable on the same domain name.

Notably, I would like to keep the main domain under route53 control rather than delegating the entire address to Azure.

What would be the recommended method for integrating the 2 public cloud services, I am unsure if I should manually add CNAME records etc for the required Azure services or if I should look to delegate a subdomain to Azure's domain services directly (such as azure.example.com, while keeping example.com on route53).

Alternateively, should I register an entirely new domain (msexample.com) on azure, and if so how would I make these integrate email etc.

Thank you very much for any advice or direction on best-practices you can provide.